# @font-face stopped working in firefox

Tags: firefox, font-face

**edited again to say NEVERMIND because problem is no longer occurring(?)**

**EDITED TO ADD LINKS**

my site:

[http://www.mainstreetmassage.co/index.html](http://www.mainstreetmassage.co/index) - relative path to stylesheet

[http://www.mainstreetmassage.co/index2.html](http://www.mainstreetmassage.co/index2) - absolute path to stylesheet

copy site on same host account:

http://

www.mcdanielcounseling.com/index.html

this "copy site" is the site that got changed last night by deleting just the html and css for the blue ribbon that had the custom fonts inside it - but the actual font files are still in the "copy site"'s css folder

The 2 sites are in 2 separate folders and don't share any resources.

**END OF EDIT**

2 custom fonts used to work fine no matter what browser. I had a little trouble initially getting FF to work but sorted that a while ago by putting the font files "loose" in the css folder, not in a folder of their own, and it's worked fine since then.

All the links I made absolute, because that seemed to make the page faster, but that too was a while ago and no trouble until this morning.

The only thing I can think of that's changed is, I set up a second site on same hosting account or server, it was at first just a copy and paste of my site but I've been slowly changing it for the owner, and last night, in that site's folder only, I deleted not the custom font files, but just the references to them in the CSS file, plus the HTML element that used them - but only in the 2nd site, not mine.

Then all of the sudden today the fonts are not displaying in FF at all, on my site. I fixed it sort of by following another answer on here that suggested making the urls relative for the css, and that worked, but I am wondering what made it happen and if I need a more permanent fix.

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site in question or some code?

Comment: Added links to original question, but did something wrong b/c they don't go anywhere, but they do work if cut and pasted into browser, sorry